# Which signature version will be used when using command gradlew assembleRelease to generate signed APK?

Tags: android, gradle

When generating signed APK by clicking Build > Generate Signed APK, we have to select which signature version to be used, V1, V2 or both. 
But which signature version will be used by default when using command gradlew assembleRelease to generate signed APK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a signingConfig both v1 and v2 signature versions are enabled by default from Gradle 2.2

As specified in Google Developer's Blog [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/understanding-apk-packaging-in-android-studio-2-2.html)

In case you want to disable adding v1 or v2 signatures when building with the Android Gradle plugin, you can add these lines to your signingConfig section in build.gradle:

```
v1SigningEnabled false
v2SigningEnabled false
```

> Note: both signing schemes are enabled by default in Android Gradle
>   plugin 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

In your user home directory there is a folder called `.android` and there is a keystore file called `debug.keystore`. That keystore is used to sign the APK for debug versions.

For task `assembleRelease`, signed APK is not generated as you can find only apk file like **app-release-unsigned.apk** in the release folder and you will need to sign it manually.

Comment: I've created a key store for release, and have added signingConfigs in the build.gradle of app module, but I haven't added the signature version related configuration. So I can get a signed apk by task assembleRelease, but I don't know which signature version is used.